# Python Popup windows icon / image

Tags: python, python-3.x, popupwindow, pysimplegui

Is there a way to display custom image / logo on the title bar of a popup window in python.

Using simplegui most probably. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the icon in the titlebar, then your answer is likely here:

https://pysimplegui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/call%20reference/#popup-functions